# Colocar imagenes en proyecto Django

Tags: django

Quiero colocar un imagen como logo dentro de mi proyecto y que se vea en todas mis vistas, pero no se como y probé con la documentación pero no entendí bien y no lo logro.

**`style.css:`**

```
ody {
    background: white url("images/560841.jpg") no-repeat right bottom;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Como podría hacer para que se vea en todas mis vistas como un logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el manejo de vistas se suele tener un template básico y declarar el apartado que se va a estar modificado ( Por lo general el `body` ) Esto para que todas tus vistas tengan la misma estructura y solo extiendes las propiedades de la principal. Te dejo un ejemplo.

¿Esto de que te sirve?
En el template `principal.html` puedes agregar tu logo, para que no lo estés replicando en todos lados

Lo único que no entiendo es que estás declarando en el css un selector llamado `ody` por lo cual lo colocaré como un tag. Recuerda que debes llamar la variable `static de Django` para que las rutas relativas sean más fáciles, esto para que llames a tu `style.css`.

Este sería tu template principal y se llama `principal.html`, en el `div .container` vamos a abrir un bloque del cual posteriormente las otras vistas se podrán alimentar. Al bloque lo llamaré `contenido`

```
{%load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--Aquí incluyes tu archivo style.css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/nombre_app/style.css' %}">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
  <!--Aquí está tu etiqueta que tedrá la imagen como logo-->
  <ody></ody>
</div>

<div class="container">
 {% block contenido %}
 {% endblock %}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

De esa forma puedes incluir todo esto en tus otras vistas. Por ejemplo en `ventas.html`. La ruta de donde debes extender es el nombre de tu App (No del proyecto) y el template `principal.html`

```
{% extends 'nombre_app/principal.html' %}
{% block content %}
 <!--Aquí todo tu contenido de ventas -->
{% endblock %}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.